# scrollTop function not working in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, scrollbar

I just started to use jQuery, and I have a two column layout using twitter bootstrap. The CSS file is:

```
html, body {
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 100%;  }
.span8, .span4 { 
     overflow: auto; }
```

This gives the span4 and span8 separate scrollbars. In the span8 part, there is a list of entries and I want to add some features to the scrollbar. But at present, scrollTop seems not responding at all, even the simplest one. For example, if I have something like this in the .js file ("entry" is the class for those entries):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.entry').scrollTop(1000);});
```

I assume it would put the scrollbar below the top of the first entry 1000 pixels, but when I load the page, the scrollbar is still at the very top. Or I tried to read the value of the scrollbar position using scrollTop, it always give me 0. I'm sure I must have messed up something, anyone has suggestions? Thanks.

Update: After some study, it turned out that I made a stupid mistake. ".scrollTop" can only be invoked by the selector whose div has a scrollbar. In my case, I can't use `$('.entry').scrollTop(1000);`. Instead, I should use `$('.span8').scrollTop(1000);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.entry').offset().top + 1000
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: It seems not working. By the way, I have disable the scrollbar for the "html, body" using "overflow:hidden", is "$('html, body')" still working?

Comment: It not working for me too after putting the `html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}`. Remove the `overflow: hidden;` once and try again..

Comment: Actually I want to keep the body's scroll-bar hidden, thus I'd rather not to change that part...